# Line plot - Matlab

Tags: matlab

When I run this code:

```
pts= [-1 0; 0 1; 1 0; 0 -1];
xCenter = 0;
yCenter = 0;
plot(xCenter,yCenter,pts(:,1), pts(:,2),'g');
```

I get this plot:
[image]

What do I need to change so I will plot the + sign, that all the lines will start from the center.

Comment: Yes. This is why I am struggling for.  I also tried: `for i = 1 : length(pts)
    plot(xCenter,yCenter,pts(i,1), pts(i,2),'g');
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the origin between every pair of points

```
pts= [-1 0; 0 0; 0 1; 0 0; 1 0; 0 0; 0 -1];
```

otherwise you're skipping between the end-points of the "+", which is why you get 3 sides of a square.

You could do this automatically with something like

```
pts= [-1 0; 0 1; 1 0; 0 -1];
xCenter = 0;
yCenter = 0;

% Initialise the array to all be the center point
newPts = repmat( [xCenter, yCenter], size(pts,1)*2-1, 1 );
% Every other row comes from the original "pts"
newPts(1:2:2*size(pts,1),:) = pts;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a cleaver way to automatically create a new pts (newPts) that will have the xCenter,yCenter (0,0) after every odd element from the original pts?

Comment: @alirazi See my edit